# Google tag assistant reports: “Same web property ID is tracked twice”when trying to install google analytics code

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I was trying to install google analytics code into our google tag manager at first I installed the GTM and add a tag which I grabbed from tracking ID and after all that it doesn't seem to appear an analytical dashboard on my account, I was wondering how do I fix this error on Google tag assistant and also to have the dashboard appear. thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

it seems you might have added analytics code in website and then also added it in tag manager, remove the **code/ analytics id** from website, and then use tag assistant after adding code to tag manager to track properly